# IOS MWPhotobrowser issue

Tags: ios

I am using MWPhotobrowser library as a photo viewer in my app. There is an option one can set e.g..

```
Mbrowser.wantsFullScreenLayout=YES;
```

This shows the photos in fullscreen mode. All works good.

But when i use PKRevalController library in my app

```
https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController
```

It makes my photobrowser leave a space equal to height of status bar over the navigation controller. It happens when the navigation controller over the photo viewer disappears.

When i disable the wantsFullScreenLayout then it gets ok but always shows the status bar.

I dont know what is causing it. Any help will be much appreciated. Please refer to screen shot..!

[image]

Comment: I think the PKRevealer adds a view under current view and that might mess things up. I am really looking for a solution for this problem

Comment: Known issue .. check [link](https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController/issues/40) for solution/workaround Cheers!<br>
Amar.

Comment: can you give link of your source code, i will try on your code

Answer (score 0):

The `PKRevealController` is the `rootViewController` or `topViewController`. the `MWPhotoBrowser` is only a `subView` so to speak.

Easy way:
Show `MWPhotoBrowser` in a `Model` from the `PKRevealController`. instead of pushing it. maybe make the animation assemble 'pushing'

Hard way:
Hacking into `MWPhotoBrower` `viewWillAppear` and hide the `statusBar` and set it's frame to `(0, -20, weight, height+20)`.
And reset `statusBar` in `viewWillDisappear`.

<strike>My suggesting:</strike>

`MWPhotoBrowser` is really old, and hasn't been maintained any more, still using a legacy version of `SDWebImage`. maybe considering switching to other Photo Browsing lib.

Comment: I tried hacking into mwphotobrowser but didnt work. so you are suggesting mwphotobrowser is really old and i should switch to a new library, will it actually work switching to new library?

Comment: Like the new one presenting image in current ViewController with mainWindow. Can't exactly remember the name. Sorry